# Input string was not in a correct format in replace mehod

Tags: asp.net, replace, string-formatting

I want to edit a text and there is some dynamic fields in it, so i used replace method to have these fields in special place in context. my problem is when i want to replace these fields in context it gave me an error:
Input string was not in a correct format.
the error happen in the EmailBody. and the content of Body variable is this:

```
FROM: {JournalAbbreviation} &lt; {JournalAbbreviation}@test.com&gt;<br />
SUBJECT: Review Submitted Successfully for {JournalAbbreviation}<br />
BODY:<br />
Manuscript ID:&nbsp; {ManuscriptID}<br />
Title: {Title}<br />
<br />
<br />
Dear {Prefix} {Firstname} {Middlename} {Lastname},<br />
<br />
Thank you for your review for {JournalAbbreviation}. We appreciate your time and feedback and hope to collaborate with you again in the near future.<br />
<br />
Kind regards,<br />
{FirstnameSender}, PhD<br />
Associate Editor<br />
{JournalFullName}<br />
http://{JournalAbbreviation}.test.com<br />
<br />
```

This code has been saved as string in database and Body variable fill with these code.

```
 Body = Body.Replace("{Prefix}", "{0}");
        Body = Body.Replace("{Firstname}", "{1}");
        Body = Body.Replace("{Middlename}", "{2}");
        Body = Body.Replace("{Lastname}", "{3}");
        Body = Body.Replace("{ManuscriptID}", "{4}");
        Body = Body.Replace("{Title}", "{5}");
        Body = Body.Replace("{JournalAbbreviation}", "{6}");
        Body = Body.Replace("{FullJournalName}", "{7}");
        Body = Body.Replace("{PrefixSender}", "{8}");
        Body = Body.Replace("{FirstnameSender}", "{9}");
        Body = Body.Replace("{MiddlenameSender}", "{10}");
        Body = Body.Replace("{LastnameSender}", "{11}");
        string **EmailBody** = String.Format(Body, Prefix, Firstname, Middlename, Lastname, ManuscriptID, Title, JournalAbbreviation, FullJournalName, PrefixSender, FirstnameSender, MiddlenameSender, LastnameSender);
```

The print out is:

FROM: IEEE < IEEE@test.com>
SUBJECT: Review Submitted for IEEE

Manuscript ID:  102-IEEE-2013
Title: Text mining using biclustering method
International Electrical Engineering

Dr John Smith,

A review has been submitted for the above-mentioned manuscript.

Kind regards,
International Electrical Engineering 
http://IEEE.test.com

Can any body help me to find the the problem?
Thanks

Comment: I add it to the answer.

Comment: No, I mean to debug it and see whats on the body, anyway I found your issue and I replay you,

Comment: It gave me the same error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see in your body that you have `{JournalFullName}` and you do not change with some number anywhere on your replace, so this (and other like this) give this error.

To avoid this error ether change this parameter to `{{JournalFullName}}` ether be sure that you replace it also because the symbols `{}` wait to have a number inside that reflect the parameter on the Format.

Comment: Thanks for responding, but i can not understand you, because i replace it with it's variable and number 7! 
So would you mind please explain me more?

Comment: @SaeedTalaee No you are not, there is a typo there ! `FullJournalName` != `JournalFullName`

Comment: It gave me the same error, I thing if it doesn't find JournalFullName, it shouldn't give error. because it will count {JournalFullName} as a ordinary word!

Comment: @SaeedTalaee No is not an ordinary word, because you use the `{}` and is giving the error you see.

Comment: My last question is, should change in in my html code? i mean in Body?

Comment: @SaeedTalaee The `body` that you use for the `String.Format()` must only contains corrected parameters like: `{0}`. I do not know where you going to change it, but you should do that. You can change ether the body, ether the replace.